# C#: static Guid as argument of an attribute

Tags: c#, attributes, constants, guid

How can I use a static Guid as argument in an attribute?

```
static class X
{
  public static readonly Guid XyId = new Guid("---");
}

[MyAttribute(X.XyId)] // does not work
public class myClass
{
}
```

It does not work because Guid must be readonly, it can not be const. The string and byte[] representation would also be readonly.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not possible and never will be possible (barring significant changes to the .NET runtime), because `[Attributes]` are compiled as metadata and `static` variables are initialized at runtime, and of course the former cannot access the latter (except via Reflection).

If the standard

```
public const string MyGuid = "blah";
```

won't work for you, then AFAIK the only way to achieve what you want, is with Reflection.

Comment: Nope, you can have const strings.

Comment: Since the `string` I declared above is constant, it's compiled into the application and hence is available for use in `Attributes`.

Comment: so the solution is to put the string into a const, and pass it instead of a guid as argument, then the guid is instantiated in the constructor of the attribute?

Comment: Correct. Because the string is constant, the Guid constructed from that string must therefore also be constant. Hence it all works happily at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no a good way to pass Guid to attribute.
Only workaround would be to use another type for that and convert it to Guid.

Comment: Yes, this would be great, but what "other type" would it be?

Comment: Well, it would be string. But of course the GUID would not be type-safe.